# Jetty ldap authentication

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap, jetty, jaas

I am trying to set up Jetty 9.1 with ldap (active directory) authentication. I have googled like crazy without finding the answers I need... I extended the included demo-app to use ldap. When visitng the page I get the following message: Problem accessing /test-jaas/auth.html. Reason: !role . In the console / logs I see "Found User?: true", so the user is found but it is the role matching that is causing problems.

Hope someone can give me some pointers...

Here are my configurations:

**test-jaas.xml:**

```
<Set name="securityHandler">
 <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.security.ConstraintSecurityHandler">
  <Set name="loginService">
   <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.jaas.JAASLoginService">
    <Set name="name">Test JAAS Realm</Set>
    <Set name="loginModuleName">xyz</Set>
   </New>
  </Set>
 </New>
</Set>
```

**login.conf:**

```
xyz {
org.eclipse.jetty.jaas.spi.LdapLoginModule required
   debug="true"
   contextFactory="com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory"
   hostname="host.domain"
   port="389"
   bindDn="CN=xxx,OU=xxx,..."
   bindPassword="xxxx"
   authenticationMethod="simple"
   forceBindingLogin="true"
   userBaseDn="ou=xxxx,..."
   userRdnAttribute="cn"
   userIdAttribute="userPrincipalName"
   userPasswordAttribute="unicodePwd"
   userObjectClass="user"
   roleBaseDn="ou=xxxx,..."
   roleNameAttribute="cn"
   roleMemberAttribute="userPrincipalName"
   roleObjectClass="group";
};
```

**web.xml contains these:**

```
  <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>JAAS Role</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/auth.html</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
  <auth-constraint>
      <role-name>user</role-name>
       <role-name>*</role-name>
       <role-name>**</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>  
  </security-constraint>

  <login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>Test JAAS Realm</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
      <form-login-page>
        /login.html
      </form-login-page>
      <form-error-page>
        /authfail.html
      </form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
  </login-config>

  <security-role>
    <role-name>user</role-name>
  </security-role>
  <security-role>
    <role-name>*</role-name>
  </security-role>
  <security-role>
    <role-name>**</role-name>
  </security-role>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the answer, putting it here so others might have use for it.

I was trying to authenticate against an ou. I had set the correct name in the web.xml auth-constraint and security-role but without luck. When I changed the roleBaseDn to a real group and adding that to the web.xml it started to work. In many examples that I have found they use an ou in the roleBaseDn, don't know if it is because of some configuration in our AD or what but didn't work for me...

So:

roleBaseDn="cn=group,ou=xxx,..."

and adding the group to web.xml was the answer. :)

Comment: That is weird and does not seems logical from an LDAP perspective. Normally, you specify the root context (typically an OU object) and the JAAS module should search for roles (groups in your case) from there. In your config, you will never be able to use different groups with multiple security constraints.

Comment: I see what you are meaning. In my case that is not an issue because one group is enough. 

After reading up on AD a bit I also realized that I was trying to do a member search in a container. When looking in the AD the containers don't have members.